# What does m/master means in git in terms of branch?

Tags: git, repo

When i do `git log --oneline` in my local repo i see `m/master` as a branch what does `m/master` mean here? Does that represent my local master branch.

```
$ git log --oneline
7c5a48b (HEAD -> default, origin/featureBranch, origin/master, m/master, master) commit xyz changes
.
.
.
```

Also i see HEAD pointing to `default`, is `default` another branch? Is `default` a standard default branch ? I thought `master` was default standard branch as i can see both `master` and `default` as branches ?

Comment: Are you using `repo init` and `repo sync` to download the repositories?

Comment: yes @ElpieKay I am using `repo init` and `repo sync`

Comment: yes `default` is another branch and that's even the one currently checked out (that's why `HEAD` is pointing toward it)

Answer (score 8):

`m/master` is a special ref used by the `repo` tool. Its full name is `refs/remotes/m/master`. Although it uses `refs/remotes`, it's not a real remote tracking branch like `origin/master`. The repository doesn't have a remote named `m`.

To initialize a `repo` workspace, we use

```
repo init -u <url_to_manifest_repo> -b <branch> -m <path_to_manifest>
```

`-b <branch>` instructs `repo` to checkout `<branch>` after cloning the manifest repository. If it's omitted, it defaults to `-b master`. But the `repo` tool creates `refs/heads/default` in replacement of `refs/heads/<branch>`. The `master` also exists in your case, because `master` does exist in the remote repository and has once been checked out or created in the local repository.

The `repo` tool creates `refs/remotes/m/<branch>` for every project defined in `<path_to_manifest>` and for the manifest repository. In your case, it's `m/master`. If you use `-b foo`, it would be `m/foo`. In the manifest repository, the value of `m/<branch>` is `refs/remotes/origin/<branch>`. In the project repositories, its value is `refs/remotes/origin/<upstream>` or `refs/remotes/origin/<revision>`. `upstream` and `revision` are defined in the manifest.

Comment: This answer was useful, but it wasn't immediately obvious to me why this `ref` was created. Now I see that I can be in any git repository in the repo, and they can each have their own set of unique branches, but I can always get back to what the manifest specifies by checking out `m/<path_to_manifest>` instead of having to look it up in the manifest and manually check it out.

Answer (score 1):

It could mean a number of things.

You probably have a remote called `m` which has a branch called `master` that points to that commit.

You might have a branch or tag called `m/master` that points to that commit.

Or generally speaking, you might have a reference called `m/master` that's pointing to that commit.

Hard to tell from the text alone. Git would show the references in different colors so you  could tell the difference. You can verify by looking at the `.git/refs` folder and looking for that master branch or potentially the `.git/packed-refs` file if that exists. Or more directly, you can list all refs with `git show-ref` so you can see where that ref might exist. Depending on where it is in the refs folder determines what kind of reference it is.

Comment: Can you point out to some documentation around the first line `HEAD -> default, origin/featureBranch, origin/master, m/master, master`? What does the general output represent?

Comment: It is probably documented, I just wouldn't know where to look. You could try digging through the online [book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References). But from my understanding, of the different special types of references, the prefixes are removed when named. Such as branches (`refs/heads/`), tags (`refs/tags/`), remote branches (`refs/remotes/`), and  so on. Other references will be shown in full.